# Application Output just shows nothing for a simple Hello World

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I'm on Elementary OS and just installed "MonoDevelop". I'm forced to use C#. However, it came up with a simple Hello World default program:

```
using System;

namespace HelloCsharp{
    class MainClass{
        public static void Main (){
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that my "Application Output" panel is empty. 
At least it creates a new line (yet an empty line). I've selected it and thus it is shown as a "blue bar" in the following screenshot.

[image]

The checkboxes "Run on external console" and "Pause console output" are checked.

[image]

Anyone has any suggestions?

Am I right that this code normally should give me an output in this panel?

Comment: I'm not sure adding C# rant will get you very far.

Comment: You must be fun at partys...

Comment: Project > "solutionName" Options > Edit > Run > General > Configuration (select "Debug"). Check the checkboxes "Run on external console" and "Pause console output"

Comment: @cubrr Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, these boxes are already "true". :( Edited my answer with the appropriated screenshot.

Comment: @OddDev In that case you should be seeing an external terminal pop up when you start the program. If this is not the case, you might need to create a symlink to whatever terminal you prefer in `/usr/bin/` and name it `xterm`. This is not an issue with C# like you implied earlier. If you untick those checkboxes, MonoDevelop should redirect output to the Application Output view.

Comment: @OddDev If nothing else works, create a post-build script that executes `mono <path-to-your-built-executable>`.

Comment: @cubrr Nah, was just joking around. I've already assumed that this is some configuration/Linux stuff. 
However, you are awesome! I've unticked the "Run on external console" (quite logical if I think about it) and now it works! Thank you! You may want to create an answer, so that I can mark it as correct.

Comment: what version of MonoDevelop is this?

Comment: @knocte It's version 5.9.4. Should be the most recent one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tick `Run on external console`, MonoDevelop will start your program...in an external console. By default this is `/usr/bin/xterm`. You can create a symlink to your preferred console application by creating a symlink to it in `/usr/bin/` and naming it `xterm`.

If you wish to receive the output to the `Application Output` pad instead, untick `Run on external console`.