# Creating A Simple Solution: hello world in mono

Tags: linux, mono, console-application, monodevelop

***This project builds from the IDE but won't run.  There's no "run" button...***

How do I [create a simple solution](http://www.monodevelop.com/documentation/creating-a-simple-solution/)?  I eventually selected "Shared Project":

[image: shared..]

which gave me a generated class.  Modifying it slightly:

```
using System;
namespace bravo
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }

    }
}
```

Nor do I have [options to configure how the app runs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31366115/262852).  I must've created the wrong type of application...not a console app:

[image]

Comment: My recommendation to you is to give up Mono and MonoDevelop. Use Visual Studio Code + .NET Core SDK, you can develop .NET Core console apps on Linux.

Comment: Create a new project and look under the "Other" section, you will find a Console Project template there.

Answer (score 0):

```
thufir@dur:~/Projects$ 
thufir@dur:~/Projects$ chmod +x console/console/obj/x86/Debug/console.exe 
thufir@dur:~/Projects$ 
thufir@dur:~/Projects$ ./console/console/obj/x86/Debug/console.exe 
Hello World!
thufir@dur:~/Projects$ 
thufir@dur:~/Projects$ tree console/
console/
├── console
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── Debug
│   │       ├── console.exe
│   │       └── console.pdb
│   ├── console.csproj
│   ├── console.csproj.user
│   ├── obj
│   │   └── x86
│   │       └── Debug
│   │           ├── console.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache
│   │           ├── console.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
│   │           ├── console.exe
│   │           └── console.pdb
│   ├── Program.cs
│   └── Properties
│       └── AssemblyInfo.cs
├── console.sln
└── console.userprefs

7 directories, 12 files
thufir@dur:~/Projects$ 
thufir@dur:~/Projects$ cat console/console/Program.cs 
using System;

namespace console
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
thufir@dur:~/Projects$
```

It was in `.NET`:

[image: C#]

I was looking for a `mono` project, versus `C#`.

Thanks SushiHangover.